# PHP Class: Call function inside class inside if statement

Tags: php

```
class ValidatorClass{
    public function PersonAge($firstPar, $secondPar){
        if(!$this->isFloat($firstPar)){
            return 0;   
        }
        if(!$this->isNumber($secondPar)){
            return 0;   
        }/*the function contiues to a select query that works if I remove the two filters on top and returns 1 if match found(but it doesn't matter for the situation, just to clarify)*/
    }
    }//PersonAge()

    public function isFloat($inputFloat){
        return is_float($inputFloat);
    }
    public function isNumber($inputNumber){
        return is_int($inputNumber);
    }
    public function isString($inputString){
        return is_string($inputString);
    }
}
```

Basically, the filters don't work, they return 0 and the function stops, with the values being float or integer, depending on the situation. They should return true and shouldn't return 0, the function should continue. Is there another way to do the same thing? Or maybe, get this to work.

Comment: you need to show how you call this function, e.g. we need to see sample inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `is_int` check if number is INT not numeric text.
6 - this is good for is_int.
'6' - this is not good for is_int because it is string not int.

You should play with `is_numeric()` which checks if string is a number

Comment: The point is it breaks, I got the numbers right all the times but it shouldn't. I split the if statements to see where it breaks, but both if statements return 0... The first one is a float, the second is int and it should return 1 and continue, not break

Comment: So probably your parameters are strings as I mentioned at the begining. Show me exact result of `var_dump($firstPar);`

Comment: you are right, they are strings, gotta fix that now... Thanks, you've been helpful